# Express $f(x)= \tan(x+ \frac{\pi}{4})$ as a sum of an even function and an odd function

Tags: analysis

Express $f(x)= \tan(x+ \frac{\pi}{4})$ as sum of two functions and one of them has to be even and the other odd like $f(x) = e + o$,
so that $e$ is an even function and $o$ is an odd function.

Comment: $f(x)=\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2}+\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2}$.

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: The first term is an even function, the second is an odd one.

Comment: I get it now and thank you. Also can you prove that the first term is even and second term is odd?

Comment: Substitute $x\gets-x$. Moreover, this representation is unique (if $f(x)=e(x)+o(x)$, then $f(-x)=e(x)-o(x)$ - now add and subtract...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go to this step by step.

First, express the tangent function in terms of the sine function and cosine function:
$$f(x)=\frac{\sin(x+\frac{\pi}{4})}{\cos(x+\frac{\pi}{4})}$$
Make use of angle-sum identities for the sine function and cosine function:
$$f(x)=\frac{\sin(x)\cdot \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)+\cos(x)\cdot \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)}{\cos(x)\cdot \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)-\sin(x)\cdot \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)}$$
Recognize that $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$:
$$f(x)=\frac{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}{\cos(x)-\sin(x)}$$
Multiply both the denominator and numerator by $\cos(x)+\sin(x)$:
$$f(x)=\frac{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}{\cos(x)-\sin(x)}\cdot\frac{\cos(x)+\sin(x)}{\cos(x)+\sin(x)}$$
It follows that
$$f(x)=\frac{\sin^2(x)+\cos^2 (x)+2\cdot \sin(x)\cdot \cos(x)}{\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)}$$
Regarding the numerator, make use of a Pythagorean identity and a double-angle identity for the sine function. Regarding the denominator, make use of a double-angle identity for the cosine function:
$$f(x)=\frac{1+\sin(2x)}{\cos(2x)}$$
Split the fraction:
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\cos(2x)}+\frac{\sin(2x)}{\cos(2x)}$$
Express the function in terms of the secant function and tangent function:
$$f(x)=\sec(2x)+\tan(2x)$$
It can be derived that $f(x)=e(x)+o(x)$ holds since $\sec(-z)=sec(z)$ and $\tan(-z)=-\tan(z)$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to do it:

Use the formula for the tangent of a sum to render

$\tan(x+\pi/4)=\frac{1+\tan x}{1-\tan x}$

Multiply the numerator and denominator by $1+\tan x$ forcing the denominator to an even function:

$\tan(x+\pi/4)=\frac{(1+\tan x)^2}{\color{blue}{1-\tan^2 x}}$

Now just expand the binomial square in the numerator and identify the even and odd parts.  You can even simplify the odd portion using the double angle formula for tangent, just for kicks.

Comment: Thanks for catching that @amWhy.  The "boring" part was a play on the comments, but the joke is on me because somehow that comment got edited.  :-S